# Delete the current line in Vim regardless of cursor position

Tags: vim

How do I delete the current line in Vim regardless of the cursor's position?

I am aware of <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> which delete from the cursor position to the end of line, but how do I delete the entire current line irrespective of the cursor position within the line?

Is there a way to do this without explicitly moving to the start of line by using <kbd>0</kbd>?

Comment: Did you read `:h deleting`?

Comment: I recommend you do `vimtutor` at least.

Comment: This is a very basic question in vim, indeed this is among the first learnt commands in vim

Answer (score 4):

I believe `dd` does what you want.